# What happened to the HTTPS lock in Firefox 4?

Tags: security, ssl, firefox, https

Previous versions of Firefox used to have a padlock icon in the address bar whenever you browsed to a HTTPS site.

Since Firefox 4 it no longer seems to be there. What happened to it? Is there any way I can get it back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was removed in Firefox 4 - the intention now is that the site's security information is presented in the [Site Identify button](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-tell-if-my-connection-is-secure?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Site+Identity+Button). You can add a similar concept of a padlock back to the Site Identity button with the [Padlock addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/padlock-icon/).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the link to the "site identity button" info - I learnt something today!